# why is there no empty line between <p> and <a> when there is one <br> in between them

Tags: html, css

```html
<a href="google.com">google</a>
<br />
<a href="google.com">google</a>
<br />
<p>This is first paragraph.</p>
<br />
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
```

The above code produces the same output even if you remove the `<br>` tag between the `<p>` and the `<a>` tag. `<br>` tag breaks the line and `<p>` being a block level element should start in a new line, i.e. it should again breaks the line before itself. So shouldn't there be an empty line in between the `<p>` and the `<a>` tag in the output. But in the output, there's no empty line between them. Also when subsequently adding more `<br>` tags between `<a>` and `<p>`, it does create more empty lines. But just one `<br>` tag makes no difference, why ?

I tried adding a `<br>` tag in between an `<a>` tag and a `<p>` tag hoping that this would create an empty line in between the `<a>` and the `<p>` tag. But it didn't happen so with just one `<br>` tag and it produces the same output even if there were no `<br>` tag. Why is it so ?

Comment: The `<br />` just gives a break in the line, eq the following text is on the next line without a margin. The `<p>some text</p>` paragraph on the other hand has by default a margin below the paragraph. So by using a double `<br />` you'll have a white space.

Comment: beacuse p has some margin set's by user agent

Comment: but p is a block Level element and block level elements create a new line before and after itself. So shouldn't there be another empty line between 'google' and 'This is first paragraph' because <br /> breaks the line and goes to the next line and <p> being a block level element, creates another line before itself.

Comment: @bron  but p is a block Level element and block level elements create a new line before and after itself. So shouldn't there be another empty line between 'google' and 'This is first paragraph' because <br /> breaks the line and goes to the next line and <p> being a block level element, creates another line before itself.

Comment: The CSS 2.1 specification http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html has an default style for HTML 4. It is just informative and not normatized `h4, p, ul, ol` and 6 more elements `{ margin: 1.12em 0 }`

Comment: In the same spec, `<br>` has a browser style `br:before { content: "\A"; white-space: pre-line }` eq the `<br>` has a "line feed" that moves the following text to the next text-line without empty space.

Comment: @bron I understand that br moves text to the next line. but p being a block level element should again create another line before itself since e block elements create a new line before and after themselves. so again the text should be shifted to the next line after it was shifted to a new line by the br element. why isn't this happening ? why is there not another line break after the 1st line break since p is a block level element which breaks itself before and after

Comment: In this 3 cases the BR will not result in **extra** white space. (a) `Some text<br><p>Other text</p>` or (b) `<span>Some text<br></span><p>Other text</p>` or (c) `<p>Some text<br></p><p>Other text</p>` Use margin-bottom to give a `<p>` extra white space below the element. Or use `<br><br>` to have a white space of 1 text line.

Answer (score 1):

This is because a `<p>` element is a block-level element, which means it takes up the full width of its parent container and creates a new line before and after the element. So, even though there is a line break before the `<p>` element, the browser will still treat it as being on the same line as the text that precedes it.

You can do your `<a>` element displayed like `block` with `display: block` to got space between them:

```css
a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="google.com">google</a>
<br />
<a href="google.com">google</a>
<br />
<p>This is first paragraph.</p>
<br />
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
```

Also, you can use `margins`, to create space without `<br />` elements:

```css
a {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom:16px;
}
```

```html
<a href="google.com">google</a>
<a href="google.com">google</a>
<p>This is first paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: I didn't understand why the browser will still treat it as being on the same line as the text that precedes it even though there is a line break before the <p> element. p is a block Level element and block level elements create a new line before and after itself. So shouldn't there be another empty line between 'google' and 'This is first paragraph' because <br /> breaks the line and goes to the next line and <p> being a block level element, creates another line before itself.

Comment: Because your `<a>` element and `<br>` are in the one line, so `<br>` just got empty before line break, as we got element in the same line and your `<br>` get place to be in this line also, but do it for the new line, if you add the second one, it will be placed on a new line and got a spaces between. When you do it like block, `<a>` element takes all the line, so your `<br>` placed in the next line and work as it expected.

Comment: You can read more about blocks and inline elements [here](https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_blocks.asp).

Comment: Thanks @TheNikCD . I understood that <a> and <br> are inline elements and apply in the same line. But I did not understand how the first <br> will get used before line break ? <br> is supposed to break the line. You're saying that the first <br> is used up somehow without breaking the line somehow, right ? How if I may ask again ? From the second <br>, it does break the line and is used by breaking the line.

Comment: Because first `<br>` do line break on end

Comment: I dont understand. So what if it does line break. Why isn't the control moving to the next line and then since there's p, a block level element, it should create another line before itself leading to an empty line. Please can you explain clearly @TheNikCD

Comment: for `<a>...</a><br><p>...</p>` think this way: a block element will start on a new line. The `p` element starts on a new line. This is correct! Also, an inline element followed by a break will end in a newline. And the `a` tag, followed by a `br` tag, ends in a newline. So this is also correct!  all is well! Now for `<a>...</a><p>...</p>` you think this way: a block element will start on a new line.  The `p` element starts on a new line. This is correct! So whatever, in both cases, all is correct! So what can you do .... just be happy and keep coding!

Comment: you're saying p element does not create another new line because there's already a new line created by < /br> . it considers the same line as the new line. right ? im not able to get this off my mind since 2 says  @topsail